# Postgresql dump taking much longer than expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using Pgadmin4 interface for backing up my remote server database (20 GB) from a local computer. Before, when I backed it up (when it was about 10 GB), it took about 8-10 minutes, fairly standard. However, now when I back it up, it has taken over 14 hours with a failed exit code:

`Error message from server: server closed the connection unexpectedly`. Not sure if that's related at all to be honest to why it's taking so long in the first place though.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: In the postgres logs apparently this is written:

```
2020-11-15 05:00:33.475 UTC [1297] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-11-15 06:00:29.670 UTC [1297] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (9 seconds apart)
```

Or this seems more fitting to the error to be honest:

```
2020-11-15 12:44:50.427 UTC [7235] postgres@DB FATAL:  connection to client lost
```

But it doesn't make too much sense as the live DB was working fine, just the backup failed

if that's of any help to understanding the situation.

Comment: In which format are you taking the dump (plain or custom)?

Comment: I am using custom (not modifying anything besides the default settings though). Reading up on the Pgadmin wiki, it says that the file is compressed for med-larger files. Even so, I feel like something is wrong though regardless of input; is plain generally multitudes faster?

Comment: As per my knowledge, plain does not provide significant speedup.

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL server log.

Comment: Hey thank you for that - I seem to be getting a constant error like this: 


2020-11-15 05:00:33.475 UTC [1297] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-11-15 06:00:29.670 UTC [1297] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (9 seconds apart)

Unsure if that's related to this though.